# How can I orient an object on a tracked plane towards the camera in SparkAR Studio 98?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am looking for a way to orient a sceneobject on a tracked plane towards the camera via scripting in SparkAR Studio 98.
This sounds trivial, but I am having a very hard time finding the world position of the camera, and then from that generating a rotation that I can apply to the object looking at the camera.

I got it to work WITHIN the tracked plane hierarchy, so that one object would always look at the other, but as the camera is living outside of that hierarchy and coordinate system, it doesn't help me.

I am, as always, struggeling with the reactive nature of the SparkAR API, as well as the fact that things are spread out over several coordinate systems and information is hard to find on the net and quickly outdated.
My code looks like this:

```
const Scene = require('Scene');
const R = require('Reactive');
export const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

(async function () {
    Diagnostics.log("Filter activated");

    const objectToOrient = await Scene.root.findFirst('object');
    const objectParent= await Scene.root.findFirst('objectParent');
    const target = await Scene.root.findFirst('target');

    const lookAtPt = R.point(
        target.worldTransform.x,
        target.worldTransform.y,
        target.worldTransform.z);

    const lookAtTransform = objectParent.transform.lookAt(lookAtPt);
})();
```

To illustrate the concept for the reader, I have set up this scene:

[image]

The "S" appears, as soon as the underlying plane is tracked. It then stays in place, along with the tracked plane.
It should then always rotate towards the camera/device/user.
Thank you!

Comment: Just to confirm: did you ask this [on their forum](https://sparkar.facebook.com/forum/) too? (Because if you need to ask others for help, always ask in the most authoritative place first, even if you then also ask in other places. Best case, you get an answer there before you get an answer here, and you can write up the SO answer yourself to help future visitors)

Comment: Thank you, I will.
I'd also like to thank you for your amazing Primer on Bezier Curves, which, and this is no joke, heavily motivated me to start a degree in CS half a year ago, coming from automotive surface modelling. I'm loving my classes and involvement with mathematics, and that's in good part because of your great site. Thanks, Mike!

Comment: That's amazing, glad it could help make a difference! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WHAT WORKED**

Having wasted a weekend, and ten minutes after giving up, I finally found out how to do it. The actual solution is so simple that it pains me to post it, but here it goes.

Using script, I just bound the rotation of the `objectToOrient` to the rotation of the camera. That's it.

```
const S = require('Scene');
const R = require('Reactive');
const D = require('Diagnostics');

// Enter look-at-target and object that needs to look at the target here
const objectName = 'lookAtObject';
const pivotName = 'pivot';
const targetName = 'Camera';
// const targetName = 'target';

(async function () {
    D.log("Filter activated");

    const [object, pivot, target] = await Promise.all([
        S.root.findFirst(objectName),
        S.root.findFirst(pivotName),
        S.root.findFirst(targetName)])
        .catch((error) => D.log(error.message));

    const deviceTransform = target.worldTransform;
    const pivotTransform = pivot.worldTransform;

    object.transform.rotation = deviceTransform.rotation;
    object.transform.position = pivotTransform.position;

    D.log("End of Log");
})();
```

After deleting two pages of my old code, I also tried to replicate this using patches, but plugging the DeviceMotion patch into the 3D rotation of the object actually produces different and counterintuitive behaviour on my android phone. Maybe the rotation in the patch and the one actually generated by the device don't line up, I'd be very interested in comments on this topic.

**WHAT DIDN'T WORK**

After having thought I solved the problem through angular calculations and world transforms like I posted here before, it actually wasn't working and I had to waste another two days of my life on this, troubleshooting and looking for problems in my calculations using either manually calculated angles between vectors, quaternions or all variations of `lookAt` that SparkAR offers.

On the way I learned about the DeviceMotion-module, which I hoped would fix the problem that I couldn't get an updated world-position of the camera into my scene. I wanted to use this position to calculate the angular difference between two vectors, and then from that rotate the object by that angle. Like most of the solutions, this worked perfectly in the editor, but not on my phone.
Unfortunately it wouldn't update once in the scene. After some debugging I found out that DeviceMotion.worldTransform ACTUALLY ONLY CONTAINS A ROTATION, but doesn't throw an error when its positional coordinates are accessed.
I find this package EXCESSIVELY frustrating to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is another simple way to do it with `lookAt` method. It seems like it works a little bit different — it always rotates the object towards the camera position in the world space, instead of binding the camera rotation to the object rotation.

```
const Scene = require('Scene');

(async function () {

    const camera = await Scene.root.findFirst('Camera');
    const tracker = await Scene.root.findFirst('planeTracker');
    const plane = await Scene.root.findFirst('plane');

    // Get the camera world space position
    const cameraPositionSignal = tracker.worldTransform.inverse().applyToPoint(camera.worldTransform.position);

    // Apply the rotation of the relative transform between plane tracker and camera world position
    plane.transform.rotation = tracker.transform.lookAt(cameraPositionSignal).rotation;

    // Bring object back to the plane tracker origin
    plane.worldTransform.position = tracker.worldTransform.position;

})();
```

Probably, the `lookAt` method was not working properly at the time of Spark AR Studio 98 was active. This works in the currently latest 120 version.