# How to use SparkAR's LookAt when parents of the object to rotate have a rotation

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, spark-ar-studio

In SparkAR I want to have an element (called `toRotate`) that always looks at the camera, similarly to what already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284072/how-can-i-orient-an-object-on-a-tracked-plane-towards-the-camera-in-sparkar-stud/65959164#65959164) (but the accepted solution is not satisfactory to me and I do not have enough reputation to answer with a comment to it).

The catch is that this element is in a hierarchy that cannot be modified: the order must **absolutely** be `root->planeTracker->parent->toRotate` as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEYkf.png) (seems like I do not have enough reputation to inbed the image).

By using the `lookAt` function (thanks to [this github repo](https://github.com/aferriss/spark-ar-lookat-example/blob/master/lookAtExample/scripts/script.js) I understood that I had to create a `toRotateDuplicate` sibiling to `toRotate` and with same local position, and then use its transform instead) I can have it working just fine when in the Editor but once I try it on device my `toRotate` has a weird rotation instead..

After some tests, I could tell that the issue was coming from the fact that the `planeTracker` has a rotaion equal to Quaternion.Identity only on editor, while on device the value varies.
This is also proved by the fact that if replacing the `planeTracker` by an empty node and applying a not-identity rotation to it, we have the "weird rotation" issue even on editor.

This is my code:

```
const Scene = require("Scene");
const Reactive = require("Reactive");

const find = e => Scene.root.findFirst(e);

(async function () {
  const toRotate = await find('toRotate');
  const toRotateDuplicate = await find('toRotateDuplicate');
  const camera = await find('Camera');
  toRotate.worldTransform.rotation = toRotateDuplicate.worldTransform.lookAt(camera.worldTransform.position).rotation;
})();
```

Since I am using world transform I shouldn't have issues about rotations right?
What should I do then?

Please note that the solution accepted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64336507/12647638) doesn't work for me: the object only looks at the camera if the camera is looking at the center of the object, plus if I move the camera around without rotating it I can see that the object is not updating its rotation to continue to look at the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an "hacky" solution:
Create another sibiling to our `toRotate` called `cameraDuplicate`, which mirrors the worldPosition of the `Camera` object.. Since all used transform in the `lookAt` logic are on the same hierarchy level now, I can use local transforms instead of the world ones ^^'

This is the updated code:

```
const Scene = require("Scene");
const Reactive = require("Reactive");

const find = e => Scene.root.findFirst(e);

(async function () {
  const toRotate = await find('toRotate');
  const toRotateDuplicate = await find('toRotateDuplicate');
  const camera = await find('Camera');

  const cameraDuplicate = await find('cameraDuplicate');
  cameraDuplicate.worldTransform.position = camera.worldTransform.position;
  toRotate.transform.rotation = toRotateDuplicate.transform.lookAt(cameraDuplicate.transform.position).rotation;
})();
```

I'm not a big fan of it since: it implies creating a second sibiling (as if one wasn't enough) and doesn't clarify my rotation issue but only avoids it.. So please provide your solutions and I will accept it if less hacky than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

For people still searching now, this code worked for me to make a panel face the camera. panelParent is a child of the planeTracker and panel is its child.

```
  const panelPosSignal = panelParent.worldTransform
    .inverse()
    .applyToPoint(camera.worldTransform.position);

   panel.transform.rotation =
    planeTracker.transform.lookAt(panelPosSignal).rotation;
```